# Eventos en tablas pivot laravel

Tags: laravel

¿Como puedo definir un evento con sus respectivos listener a una tabla pivote que no tiene modelo en laravel?

Alguien puede darme un ejemplo.

Comment: Revisa el siguiente artículo: [How To Fire An Event on Pivot Table Operations In Laravel](https://ctf0.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/how-to-fire-an-event-on-pivot-table-operations-in-laravel/)

Comment: Gracias por el articulo, pensaba que laravel soportaba la característica de eventos en pivotes pero me he dado cuenta que no. finalmente decidí llamar a mis jobs manualmente desde el controlador luego de insertar en el pivote.

Comment: Podrías crear modelos de tus tablas intermedias y realizar esa lógica también ahí. Hay diferentes soluciones, espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Lo fue, muchas gracias!